# Why Namenode is not coming UP in HDFS on kubernetes

Tags: hadoop, kubernetes, hdfs, kubernetes-helm

I tried running HDFS on k8s using this project. I got journal node and zookeeper Up and running but if I see namenode it is not going to Error state

[image]

If I look after the logs I see it as hostname could not be resolved. Then I tried seeing the /etc/hosts entry of the file on the boot up script, IP and hostname for name is not set

[image]

I'm not using any customized image just using the same helm charts as it was.
What should I need to do If I want name node to be up and running

Helm Chart Link: https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/kubernetes-HDFS/tree/master/charts

Comment: Can you paste the helm chart repo in your question?

Comment: Please find the link of the helm chart that I'm using https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/kubernetes-HDFS/tree/master/charts

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve], including any relevant fragments of the Helm chart, and the actual error messages (as text, not image files).  The [help/on-topic] also has some descriptions of what's on-topic for Stack Overflow, and deploying a prebuilt Helm chart doesn't seem like the sort of programming question that's encouraged here.

Comment: Which AWS region are you in?

Comment: Why is your namenode trying to connect to an EC2 address rather than a k8s service?